# What is the correct way to create a data model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Beginner here,
I want to create a data model with Mongoose like this:

```
{
 "country": "Spain"
 "products": [
          {
            "product": "product1"
            "price": "5"
          },
          {
            "product": "product2"
            "price": "8"
          }
 ]
}
```

I've seen some tutorials but every single one of them creates just products (not nested like mine is). Or is it even the right strategy? Or is it a better solution to create something like this?

```
{
 "country": "Spain",
 "product": "product1",
 "price": 10, 
},
{
 "country": "Spain",
 "product": "product2",
 "price": 15, 
},
{
 "country": "Germany",
 "product": "product1",
 "price": 12, 
}
```

In this case, I know how to do it:

```
mongoose.model('Product', { 
  "country": { type: String, required: true },
  "product": { type: String, required: true }, 
  "price": { type: Number, required: true }
})
```

But in the first case, I don't know how to create it.
Overall my intention is to be able to display products that will be grouped by countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:
First, you could use [subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)
They allow you to define products inside the Country schema.

```
  import mongoose from 'mongoose';
  const { Schema } = mongoose;

  const countrySchema = new Schema({
    products: [{ name: {type: String}, price: {type: Number} }],
    name: {type: String}
  });
export default mongoose.model('Country', countrySchema);
```

Another way would be to define 2 different models, and have a many-many relationship between the 2, meaning one country can "own" many products and a product can belong to many countries. This would allow you to query countries and products separately, but also see which product a country has or which countries a product belongs to.
This works like this:
You can see about how to declare and query such models [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    price: {type: Number},
    countries: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Country"}]
})
const ProductModel = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

const countrySchema = new Schema({
    products: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product" }],
    name: {type: String}
  });
const CountryModel = mongoose.model('Country', countrySchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the second strategy is right
And if you want group product by country you could use $group in aggregate function if mongo or mongodb